# Create variable from data element on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, tags, var

We have a script run early on our page that feeds values to a third party.

```
foo.bar.myPage({
    "myId": "12345",
    "myName": "My name is Joe",
});
```

I want to create a new variable using one of those values and use it for something else.  I can't figure out how to grab the value from above.  I do not have access to the code above - need to do this using javascript or jquery via a CMS.  Help?

```
var valueFromMyId = $(myId);
alert (valueFromMyId);
```

Obviously I want "12345" to fire in my alert.

Comment: Impossible to tell, we have no clue what myPage() does and what it sets

Comment: We didn't know that `myPage` function does. You can print `foo.bar` with `console.log(foo.bar)` and see if you find your information somewhere there ...

Comment: Neither do I... that is the problem :)   I will try that

Comment: @Dhruv how shoudl that help? He need the values, not the parameter names. Even if he knows them, what should he do with it? And `arguments` only work inside a function, where he has no access to ...

Comment: Try to put the object in a variable or store it in some object before passing it to this function, and then search that object for the key, if I got your question right.

Comment: @Ninja was my idea too, but he wrote he has no access to that part of the code, so he can't edit it ...

Comment: @user3390251 Can't you find the `myPage` function somewhere in the code? There you should see what it does with the data.

Comment: edited above to show what the myPage function is doing

Comment: Great. Try `console.log(window.3P_ITEM);`, maybe there is a function like `var myId = window.3P_ITEM.getId();`.

Comment: Great, Yeah now you can access the way @eisbehr suggested..

Comment: window.3P_ITEM shows me the third party's code and their functions, but not what my team is doing to generate the ID for them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure somewhere there is the data. ;) Can you see what's inside the `3P_ITEM.setId` function?

Comment: Edited above - I messed something up trying to hide the 3rd party name.  SetId was something different - its the addMyId function that I am after.   I added both what's inside the addMyId function above  (the third party's code I believe and the reference to it in our code)

Answer (score 0):

I Tried something like this:

```
foo = {
       "bar":{
           "myPage":function(param){
                     console.log("inside"+param);
             }
      }};

foo.bar.myPage(123); //print inside 123
```

Now Try this to override, if you can access foo.bar.

```
var backup = foo.bar.myPage
foo.bar.myPage = function(param){
          console.log("Using params outside the actual function "+ param);
//calling the actual function which was getting called initially
              backup(param);
}
```

now every foo.bar.myPage call will go through your define method, that way you can access param before the actual function gets it.

This might not be the best way to do it. But will work if you have access to foo.bar object. Test and let me know if this helps.

Comment: For this you don't need access to the code. You will overwrite the function on runtime. The problem coulr be to overwrite the function between script load and the `foo.bar.myPage({});` line. But then it could work.

Comment: @user3390251, have you actually tried using this code snippet?